# How does C++11 type inference decide between floats or doubles?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

Consider this example of type inference:

```
auto var = 1.0 ;
```

Does this evaluate to a float or double under C++11 type inference?, can this behaviour be controlled?

Comment: as far as controlling is concerned, you can just type `float var = 1.0`, can't you?

Comment: @piokuc, I'm talking in terms of a global compiler flag

Comment: I don't think these kind of things are/should be controllable by compiler flags

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will be evaluated as a `double` and yes, you can control it.

In the standard **ISO-14882:2011**, *2.14.4 Floating literals*, point 1:

> The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L specify long double. If the scaled value is not in the range of representable values for its type, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - please, post your edit as another question. They are different things. The first one is for floating point literals, the second - for type promotions/standard conversions.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553646/what-are-the-rules-governing-precedence-during-c11-type-inference

Comment: @GearoidMurphy - answer + quotes added :)