# What are the rules governing precedence during C++11 type inference?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

What are the rules governing precedence in C++11 type inference for float/double types, for example, when inferring from an expression containing multiple types, like so:

```
auto var = float(1) * double(1);
```

Comment: That contains multiple types, sure, but it *is* only one type: `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result will be a `double`. This is called `floating point promotion`.

From the standard, **ISO 14882:2011**, *4.6 Floating point promotion*:

> 1 A prvalue of type float can be converted to a prvalue of type double. The value is unchanged.
>   2 This conversion is called floating point promotion.

---

As noted by @sftrabbit, in *5. Expressions*, paragraph 9 in the new standard:

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result.
>
> This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
>
> — If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (7.2), no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same type, the expression is ill-formed.
>   — If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
>   — Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.
>   — Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.

Comment: And §5/10 says "Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double."

Comment: @sftrabbit - that's what I was looking for :) I'll edit adding this quote.

Answer (score 2):

The type inference doesn't add anything new, the expression to the right of the '=' is evaluated as always, and the type of it is then used for the 'auto'.

It's slightly more interesting when you look at differences between 'auto var' and 'auto & var' and similar, but that wasn't your question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the types in question.  In your specific example, the standard guarantees that `sizeof(double) >= sizeof(float)` therefore the resulting type of `double * float` will always be `double`.   (this is a rule inherited from the C language, and is generally the same in many other languages which derive from C)

When initialising a variable with the `auto` keyword, the resulting type of the expression of the initialisation is determined - whether its from a function return, a calculation, a decltype, etc.     The type depends on implicit and explicit conversions available for the types which you're using.